# Esperar por un append dentro de un ciclo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente código, lo que quiero es que vaya pasando por cada uno de los registros dentro del *arreglo* `data` y lo muestre, ponga el estado **LEÍDO**, luego **PROCESADO**, por último **ELIMINADO** y continue con el otro hasta finalizar el ciclo, el código que tengo lo hace todo a la vez con todos los registros, he intentado corregir esto con esta *función* `sleep` pero no encuentro un resultado concreto

```js
function sleep(f, m) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    f();
  }, m)
}

var data = [
  'e48c56b4-aebb-4499-a7c5-64db40381183',
  'eb1cf18c-fbdb-4b0f-b775-34e4542a8675',
  '62afe7bd-2061-4121-ab50-0b181e00e85a',
  '943f1ae4-60cd-424d-94d2-7e3f66a88e1e',
  'e6140cb0-b9c9-488a-8469-f9c3a51faffd',
  '9c6b24e8-1b53-4d68-be98-672b74380491',
  'f160a7d7-7609-44c9-9839-17ebd491ea21'
];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  $('.super').append(data[i] + '<span class="pull-right label label-success">LEÍDO</span><br/>');
  sleep(() => {
    $('.super').children('span').removeClass('label-success');
    $('.super').children('span').addClass('label-warning');
    $('.super').children('span').html('PROCESADO');
  }, 2000);

  sleep(() => {
    $('.super').children('span').removeClass('label-warning');
    $('.super').children('span').addClass('label-danger');
    $('.super').children('span').html('ELIMINADO');
  }, 4000);
}
```

```css
.super {
  width: auto;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div class='container'>
  <div class='super'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una manera es tratar el array data como una cola que se va consumiendo desde otra función. La función comprueba si la cola está vacía (en cuyo caso termina) y en caso contrario quita el último elemento, lo procesa, y vuelve a ejecutarse con los elementos restantes.

```js
var data = [
  'e48c56b4-aebb-4499-a7c5-64db40381183',
  'eb1cf18c-fbdb-4b0f-b775-34e4542a8675',
  '62afe7bd-2061-4121-ab50-0b181e00e85a',
  '943f1ae4-60cd-424d-94d2-7e3f66a88e1e',
  'e6140cb0-b9c9-488a-8469-f9c3a51faffd',
  '9c6b24e8-1b53-4d68-be98-672b74380491',
  'f160a7d7-7609-44c9-9839-17ebd491ea21'
];

function sleep(f, m) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    f();
  }, m)
}

function procesar_y_eliminar() {
  if(data.length===0) {
     return;
  } 
  var registro=data.pop();
  var elemento=jQuery('<span class="pull-right label label-success">LEÍDO</span><br/>');
  $('.super').append(registro).append(elemento);
  sleep(() => {
    elemento.removeClass('label-success');
    elemento.addClass('label-warning');
    elemento.html('PROCESADO');
  }, 2000);

  sleep(() => {
    elemento.removeClass('label-warning');
    elemento.addClass('label-danger');
    elemento.html('ELIMINADO');
  }, 4000);
  
  sleep(()=> {
    procesar_y_eliminar();
  },5000);
}
 
procesar_y_eliminar();
```

```css
.super {
  width: auto;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div class='container'>
  <div class='super'></div>
</div>
```

Este mismo comportamiento se podría mostrar un poco más intuitivamente si la función sleep retornara una promesa, tal que pudiésemos hacer `then` sobre su salida. Es como intuitivo usar `then` para indicar que una cosa ocurre después de otra.

Este es el mismo ejemplo pero promisificando el sleep. Nótese que ahora el contenido de `procesar_y_eliminar` no son dos sleep con diferentes intervalos, sino uno seguido del otro mediante `then`. Esto permitiría ejecutar no sólo dos sino N pasos sobre cada objeto sin generar más anidación ni tener que calcular el intervalo para cada uno.

```js
var data = [
  'e48c56b4-aebb-4499-a7c5-64db40381183',
  'eb1cf18c-fbdb-4b0f-b775-34e4542a8675',
  '62afe7bd-2061-4121-ab50-0b181e00e85a',
  '943f1ae4-60cd-424d-94d2-7e3f66a88e1e',
  'e6140cb0-b9c9-488a-8469-f9c3a51faffd',
  '9c6b24e8-1b53-4d68-be98-672b74380491',
  'f160a7d7-7609-44c9-9839-17ebd491ea21'
];

function sleep(m) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, m)
    });
}

function procesar_y_eliminar() {
  if (data.length === 0) {
     return;
  }
  var registro = data.pop();
  var elemento = $('<span class="pull-right label label-success">LEÍDO</span><br/>');
  $('.super')
    .append(registro)
    .append(elemento);
  return sleep(2000)
    .then(() => {
        elemento
            .removeClass('label-success')
            .addClass('label-warning')
            .html('PROCESADO');
        return sleep(2000);
    }).then(() => {
        elemento
            .removeClass('label-warning')
            .addClass('label-danger')
            .html('ELIMINADO');
        return sleep(2000);
    }).then(() => {
        return procesar_y_eliminar();
    });

}

procesar_y_eliminar();
```

```css
.super {
  width: auto;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div class='container'>
  <div class='super'></div>
</div>
```

Hay maneras más elaboradas (aunque no necesariamente mejores). Yo he ocupado la librería [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) (más rápida y versátil que las promesas nativas), que tiene el método [Promise.map](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) el cual te permite ejecutar promesas con un determinado índice de concurrencia. Puedes ejecutar de a una, de a dos, etc, hasta todas al mismo tiempo.

Creo que en este caso **usar arrays de promesas es innecesario** y no serviría más que como prueba de concepto. En realidad lo más eficiente sería buscar una librería de colas como [queue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/queue) o [d3-queue](https://github.com/d3/d3-queue) que son específicamente para este caso de uso.

Comment: Me gusta tu solución, solo cambié tu `data.pop();` por un `data.shift();` para que lo hiciera ordenadamente, quisiera saber si en definitiva esto no se puede realizar dentro de un ciclo `for` como tal

Comment: Se puede hacer de maneras más elegantes, por ejemplo retornando una promesa desde sleep se podrían concatenar los eventos PROCESADO y ELIMINADO. Y usando map sobre el array se podría obtener un array de promesas e irlas consumiendo en forma paulatina. Pero nada de eso te permitiría usar un `for`, porque el `for` seguirá su curso sin importar qué pongas entre medio. Tendrías que implementar tú mismo un análogo de `for` que esperase a una instrucción `next()` para proseguir.

Comment: Gracias por la explicación, podrías añadir a tu pregunta el breve ejemplo con las promesas? En principio esta fue la solución que busqué pero no encontré (con las promesas) muchas gracias de nuevo

Comment: añadí el mismo ejemplo usando promesas. La solución de convertir el array de uuids en un array de promesas es en realidad demasiado elaborada cuando no quieres manejar concurrencia

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que estás pensando en JavaScript con un enfoque diferente. En JavaScript no hay algo como `Thread#sleep` de Java donde el hilo actual "duerme", es decir, detiene su ejecución por un período de tiempo. En JavaScript no puedes hacer eso.

Para lograr tu objetivo simplemente aplica recursividad, volviendo a llamar a la función una vez que el registro se ha leído.

**Ejemplo**

```js
let data = [
  'e48c56b4-aebb-4499-a7c5-64db40381183',
  'eb1cf18c-fbdb-4b0f-b775-34e4542a8675',
  '62afe7bd-2061-4121-ab50-0b181e00e85a',
  '943f1ae4-60cd-424d-94d2-7e3f66a88e1e',
  'e6140cb0-b9c9-488a-8469-f9c3a51faffd',
  '9c6b24e8-1b53-4d68-be98-672b74380491',
  'f160a7d7-7609-44c9-9839-17ebd491ea21'
];

let tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');

start();

function start(i = 0) {
  if (i === data.length) {
    return;
  }

  let tr = document.createElement('tr');
  let status = document.createElement('td');
  let uuid = document.createElement('td');

  uuid.textContent = data[i];
  status.textContent = 'Leído';
  status.className = 'label-success';

  tr.appendChild(status);
  tr.appendChild(uuid);
  tbody.appendChild(tr);

  proccess(status)
    .then(() => {
      remove(status)
        .then(() => start(i + 1));
    });
}

function proccess(el) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      el.classList.remove('label-success');
      el.classList.add('label-warning');
      el.textContent = 'Procesado';
      resolve();
    }, 2000);
  });
}

function remove(el) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      el.classList.remove('label-warning');
      el.classList.add('label-danger');
      el.textContent = 'Eliminado';
      resolve();
    }, 2000);
  });
}
```

```css
td:first-of-type {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>UUID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, podrías explicar mejor porque usar el `$('.super').find('span').eq(i).html('PROCESADO');` en vez de simplificarlo a `$('super').children('span').html('PROCESADO');` ?

Comment: La función `find` [es más rápida](https://jsperf.com/jquery-children-vs-find) en general que `children`; además, usa métodos nativos del navegador.

Comment: Aunque ya aceptaste la respuesta anterior y le pediste que te muestre un ejemplo usando promesas, me tomé el tiempo de ponerte el mismo ejemplo usando ES6.

Comment: Si pudiera darte un +2 creeme que lo haría, jajaja, de nuevo, muchas gracias por tomarte tu tiempo y compartir tu conocimiento!