# Evitar que el método .each() se siga ejecutando

Tags: jquery

Como evitar, que el método .each() no se me siga ejecutando, hasta que no termine de ejecutarse .fadeToggle().

```
        $("div#texto0").html(function(){
         $("p").each(function(){
             words = $(this).html().trim().split(" ").length;
             if(words){
                pal = (60/valor) * words;
                tiempo = pal * 1000;
                $(this).fadeToggle(tiempo, function(){
                    $(this).html(" ").css("height","+=20" );
                });                 
             }              
         });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

No puedes pausar el único hilo de ejecución en JavaScript; no hay forma de hacer eso. En lugar de iterar, realiza el proceso de forma recursiva. En [ésta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/54505/esperar-por-un-append-dentro-de-un-ciclo/54515#54515) el OP plantea una situación similar a la tuya.

```
let ps = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

animate();

function animate (i = 0) {
  if (i === ps.length) { return; }

  let words = $(ps[i]).html().trim().split(" ").length;
  if (words) {
    let pal = (60/valor) * words;
    let tiempo = pal * 1000;
    $(ps[i]).fadeToggle(tiempo, function () {
      $(this).html(' ').css('height', '+=20');
      animate(i + 1);
    });
}
```

---

**Nota:** la función `jQuery#html` cuando se le pasa una función espera que **dicha función retorne un string**, cosa que no estás haciendo en tu código.